# Super 95 E10 vs Super 98?

Tags: fuel-system, transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, gasoline

Can i use Petrol: **Super 95 E10** in my car? I basically use **Super 98** on my car but the price is very expensive now 1.50 Euro cent. Where as Super 95 E10 is 1.20 Euro cent.

My car manual says i can use 95 RON or higher. Does 95 RON means Super 95 E10?

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the main part, just pay attention to the "95". It doesn't matter whether it's E10 (10% ethanol) or regular 95 RON, it will give you the same amount of detonation resistance (in theory). There is a tradeoff with using Super 95 E10 over regular 95 RON fuel, that being energy density. Ethanol has a lower energy density, which means your fuel mileage will go down.

As for whether to use the 95 or 98, use the lowest RON fuel specified for your car. You can *absolutely* use the higher RON, but you won't get any benefit from it as far as mileage or cleaning or anything. You are basically wasting your money.

Comment: I have in my car 1 liter of Super 98 now. While having Super 98 can i already load Super 95 E10 from now on? (or i need to empty the tank completely before mixing Super 95 E10)

Comment: There's no issues mixing the fuel. It just dilutes them so they are "somewhere in between".

Answer (score 2):

Note that not all cars are specified to use E10. The higher ethanol concentration may be detrimental to seals or other parts of the fuel preparation system.

Advice #1: Check with manufacturer if E10 is compatible

Advice #2: Use Super 95 (without "E10") if available.

Apart from that, @Paulster2's answer is the one you asked for.